# babel - map babel-plugins to aliased imports outside of source project

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have two Projects.  Project A and Project B.

Project B is meant to be an extension of Project A and does not have it's own packages or dependencies. Project B is included into Project A as a webpack alias.

```
const extensions = project.extensions || paths.extensions(); // external directory or internal directory

resolve: {
  modules: [
    paths.modules(), // absolute path (C:/project/node_modles)
    inProject(project.srcDir), // relative path to imported file
    'node_modules' // fallback
  ],
  alias: {
    extensions: extensions, // mapped from previoues
    store: paths.store(), // absolute path alias so Project B can consume
    containers: paths.containers(), // absolute path alias so Project B can consume
    components: paths.components() // absolute path alias so Project B can consume
  }
}
```

For everything except babel, this works fine.  The piece I seem to be missing is to give babel an absolute path of where to find babel-plugins.  It's trying to load them from the relative node_modules path of where the Project B is located instead of from Project A.

```
ERROR in ../projectB/file.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "babel-plugin-whatever" 
relative to directory "D:\\Users\\tplummer\\projectB"
```